# Are Reference Assignments Truly Atomic - Even On a 64 Bit Machine?

Tags: c#

Just wondered if the above is true or whether reference assignments are split into two operations

Is this the reason you need to use `Interlocked.Exchange`?

Can anyone confirm?

I am talking about pointer assignment here - Is that truly atomic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the type. For example [Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) assignments are not atomic in x86 mode and atomic in x64 mode. Assigning a `string` is atomic as it is a reference type and you are assigning a pointer and the size of the pointer is either 4 or 8 bytes depending on whether you are running on x86 or x64 bit mode.

Comment: Are you sure about that - If we run on a 64 bit machine the pointer is 8 bytes - Is that actually atomic?

Comment: Yes checkout the `IntPtr.Size` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx But don't be confused by the OS mode. You can run 64 bit OS and still run in x86 mode your .NET application if you explicitly specify it during compiling.